# Maintain http-session via AuthenticationToken and Authenticator

Tags: android, session, account-management

I'm writing my own Authenticator and AuthenticationService and want to manage/maintain a http-session, consisting of two cookies and one sessionid, per account in the Authenticator-System of android. So that other apps/activity can reuse the session/account and (nearly) don't have to care about sessionmanagement.

I think the right way is to use the AuthenticationToken, which every other app with the appropriate permissions can request. But my problem is, that this AuthenticationToken is only one String, but as I said I need three to maintain my session.

So what I'm searching for is a way to ask the system for three Strings which I then could append to the HTTP-Request and that on a per account base.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction or has another idea how a http-session can be maintained inside the Authenticator.

Every hint is highly appreciated!

Cheeres
  L0rdAli3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was concatenate the need values like this:

'name'='value';'name'='value';

And now it can be saved in one string, the AuthenticationToken.